# What is the difference between interactive and batch mode in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have created a Java application with the help of Maven plugin for using following maven goal:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=net.javabeat 
  -DartifactId=SampleJavaProject
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quick-start
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

When `-DinteractiveMode=false`, then project is created in batch mode, and when `-DinteractiveMode=true`, then project is created in interactive mode.
I'm confused with interactive mode and batch mode. What are those?

Comment: Can you rather explain what issues you have with understanding the [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/archetype-sect-using.html)? `When the generate goal is executed in interactive mode, it will prompt the user for all the previously listed parameters. When interactiveMode is false, the generate goal will use the values passed in from the command line.`

Comment: there is not issue, but i have understand meaning of interactive-mode and batch mode. can you tell me meaning of both?

Comment: Interactive means you need to type some answer in your keyboard and batch mode means no need to type anything maven is assuming defaults as answers.

Answer (score 97):

Batch mode causes Maven to not display "Progress: 125/150kB" style lines when running. If you are running Maven on some server and then checking the logs afterwards, these progress lines take up 90% of the log and make it basically impossible to find the stuff that matters. Setting batch mode prevents this. <s>Apart from that, I don't know any other use for batch mode. As others have said, I have never seen Maven prompt for anything during a build, regardless of whether interactive or batch mode is set.</s>

EDIT: As pointed out by @jhericks in comments, Maven can prompt for things during a build in interactive mode, for example if you run `mvn versions:set` it will prompt you for the new version to set. Trying to run such commands in batch mode will cause the build to fail with an error message that suggests re-running the build in interactive mode (or supplying the needed values as command-line parameters).

Comment: Since maven 3.5.0 when you don't use batch mode, maven will colorize the output (usin ANSI escape codes) to make it more human readable. Enabling batch mode disables this output coloring.

Comment: There are some fairly common plugin goals that are interactive.  Try `mvn versions:set` for example.

Comment: [Since Maven 3.6.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html) there is a command line option `--no-transfer-progress ` which prevent fully the output of downloads.

Answer (score 86):

The batch-mode will automatically use default values instead of asking you via prompt for those values. The batch-mode can also be activated via `--batch-mode` or `-B` on command line.

Comment: When would maven ask you for anything interactively? I haven't ever seen maven ask me for anything, except for when generating a project from an archetype. Are there other cases?

Comment: FYI you can NOT use MAVEN_OPTS=-B because that env var only specifies JVM parameters. Adding this to ~/.m2/settings.xml seems to accomplish same thing: <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>

Comment: @JavaJigs  Where is `MAVEN_CLI_OPTS` defined ?

Comment: @gvlasov There are some fairly common plugin goals that are interactive.  Try `mvn versions:set` for example.

Comment: @jhericks When I tried to run `mvn versions:set` in batch mode the build fails with an error "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.14.2:set (default-cli) on project projectname: You must specify the new version, either by using the newVersion property (that is -DnewVersion=... on the command line) or run in interactive mode" This is different from "automatically use default values instead of asking you via prompt for those values" as @khmarbaise suggested in his answer. Do you have any example that would actually use the default values?

Answer (score 28):

A common use case for `--batch-mode` is when using Maven on a Continuous Integration server, like said in this doc : [Running Maven in Batch Mode](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-batch-option).

So it will for example suppress upload messages to avoid polluting the console log.

For example, when you create a new file on GitLab through the template `.gitlab-ci.yml` for Maven, you will have the following in the variables :

```
variables:
  # This will suppress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
  # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  # As of Maven 3.3.0 instead of this you may define these options in `.mvn/maven.config` so the same config is used
  # when running from the command line.
  # `installAtEnd` and `deployAtEnd` are only effective with recent version of the corresponding plugins.
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
```

You can see that `--batch-mode` is enabled by default.

Comment: A maven cli options reference can be found here http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-embedder/cli.html